# cuSolverRf sample status alloc failed

Tags: cuda, malloc, cusolver

Running the [CuSolverRf sample](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/#cusolverrf-refactorization) with the sample `.mtx` files `lap2D_5pt_n100.mtx` and `lap3D_7pt_n20.mtx` allows the program to run smoothly. However, when I insert in my own `.mtx` file, I get an error after step 8:

> "CUDA error at cuSolverRF.ccp:649 code=2..."

I've narrowed down the problem to here:

```
checkCudaErrors(cusolverRfSetupHost(
    rowsA, nnzA, 
    h_csrRowPtrA, h_csrColIndA, h_csrValA,
    nnzL, 
    h_csrRowPtrL, h_csrColIndL, h_csrValL, 
    nnzU, 
    h_csrRowPtrU, h_csrColIndU, h_csrValU, 
    h_P, 
    h_Q, 
    cusolverRfH));
```

Which would jump to

```
    void check(T result, char const *const func, const char *const file, int const line)
{
    if (result)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUDA error at %s:%d code=%d(%s) \"%s\" \n",
                file, line, static_cast<unsigned int>(result), _cudaGetErrorEnum(result), func);
        DEVICE_RESET
        // Make sure we call CUDA Device Reset before exiting
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

My question is how does the "result" derived? and what I can do to overcome the problem or what am I doing wrong?

Additional info: my matrix is 196530 by 196530 with 2530798 nnz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error code `2` corresponds to `CUSOLVER_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED`:

[quoting the cuSOLVER documentation:](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/#cuSolverSPstatus)

> Resource allocation failed inside the cuSolver library. This is
>   usually caused by a cudaMalloc() failure.
>   To correct: prior to the function call, deallocate previously
>   allocated memory as much as possible.

This means memory for your matrix could not be allocated, probably since your GPU's memory is exceeded. Try deallocating memory (as stated in the documentation), use a smaller input matrix, or use a GPU with more memory.

Comment: I tried deallocating as mentioned but it didn't have any effect. On that note, would deallocating not remove all values stored on the GPU?

Comment: @ceeely yes it would, but maybe you have values stored in GPU memory which you do not need for cuSOLVER (i.e. from a previous step)

Comment: For context, I had my suspicions about the GPU memory thing part as I am using an old GPU (Nvidia Quadro 4000). If it's the cause, guess it's really time for a much needed upgrade.

Comment: one more thing: for future reference, do you know how the "result" value was created?

Comment: @ceeely: it is the return value of the `cusolverRfSetupHost` call, passed via the `checkCudaErrors` preprocessor macro